# Create balloon plot with ggplot2: use ..count.. to adjust size of geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to essentially create a balloon plot with `ggplot2` where the size of the points are the frequency of data at a given coordinate.

Given the data.frame `d`:

```
d = structure(list(value.x = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Not at all Knowledgeable", "Somewhat Knowledgeable", "Very Knowledgeable"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), value.y = structure(c(5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Much less knowledgeable", "Less knowledgeable", "Same as before workshop", "More knowledgeable", "Much more knowledgeable"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), .Names = c("value.x", "value.y"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to do something like:

```
ggplot(d,aes(value.x,value.y,size=..count..))+geom_point()
```

where the data points are proportional to how many times data occur, but I cannot figure out how to properly set the size of the points for what I want.

Importantly, I would like to avoid creating a new column in `d` just for counts of data as has been done with other datasets (e.g. http://www.r-bloggers.com/balloon-plot-using-ggplot2/). This seems messy and I would like to utilize `ggplot2`'s power if I can.

Comment: see `stat_sum()` ...

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: although there indeed are some nice helper functions in `ggplot`, it is often easier and more transparent to aggregate the data before feeding it to `ggplot`.

Comment: You do realize that ggplot is actually copying your data and adding a computed column, right? Why not just do it (even in a temporary data frame) on your own so you have more control? How is that "messy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @BenBolker's suggestion, I found a solution using `stat_sum()`:

```
ggplot(d, aes(value.x, value.y, size = ..n..)) + stat_sum()
```

Comment: note for good graphical design you might want to add `+scale_size_area()` to make the area rather than the radius proportional to the number of counts ...